# Javascript regex get matches as array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code snippet:

```
hash = window.location.hash;
regex = /^#id=\d{1,10}&session=(.+)$/ig;
 if (regex.test(hash)) {
  stepTo4(0, id, "start", session);
  break;    
 }
```

How do I go about getting the matched value for `\d{1,10}` in the place where `id` currently is in the method arguments, and the same with the `session`?
I've tried:

```
var m = hash.match(regex);
console.log(m);
stepTo4(0, m[0], "start", m[1]);
```

but `m[0]` just contains the same value as the `hash` variable, and `m[1]` is undefined.

Comment: `m[0]` contains the entire matched string. `m[1]` contains the first matched group, and so on. What does `console.log(m)` say? Or, what is a sample value of the hash so I can test myself?

Comment: A sample hash would be `#id=0425061&session=dc2630594257979f3edfafe412bdd16531871542`, console.log(m) outputted: `["#id=0425061&session=dc2630594257979f3edfafe412bdd16531871542"]` m[1] and m[2] are undefined

Comment: Hmm... odd. `[1]` should be that capture group in your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture it in your expression:

```
hash = window.location.hash;
regex = /^#id=(\d{1,10})&session=(.+)$/ig;
```

To use it:

```
m = hash.match(regex)
id = m[1]
```

Comment: He did capture `&session` but he said `[1]` of his match array was undefined, even though it matched it because he used `regex.test(...)` on it.

Comment: He didn't capture the \d{1,10}, only the session=(.+). I've captured it in the above pattern (notice the parenthesis)

Comment: I know but... his problem is that `m[1]` is undefined even though matched it in his regex. It shouldn't be undefined, even though he only captured session, it still shouldn't be.

Comment: Ya, I've added brackets to \d{1,10} too, but m[1] remains undefined

Comment: Ah, your JSFiddle did not include the "ig" at the end of the regex, I tried removing the "g" from mine and it works now :D

Comment: That's a weird note on `match`: "Note: If the regular expression does not include the g modifier (to perform a global search), the match() method will return only the first match in the string." It *appears* to behave in the exact opposite way: if you *do* add `g`, you get only the 'entire' match and groups get ignored.

Comment: @Jongware: weird indeed - w3schools' information is often vague and incomplete. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).